# How to know in UserControl when MainWindow (Applicatoin) is going to close ? - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Usercontrol in WPF application. I want to save logs for each usercontrol instance when it's going to close. The problem is how to identify in usercontrol whether mainwindow is going to close? There might not any 'Closed' Event like WPF window in usercontrol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a public method in your user control like:

```
public void MainAppClosing()
{
    //your code here
}
```

and in your main window's closing event call it:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
     instanceOfMentionedUserControl.MainAppClosing();
}
```

Comment: This is working generally but not for all instances of usercontrol.

Comment: what do you mean by __not for all instances__? if you explain may be I can help

Comment: if you have them in array or list you can loop through them `foreach(var uc in userControls) uc.MainAppClosing();` or if they are all in a parent like a panel or ..., you can do something like: `foreach(var uc in panel1.Controls.OfType<MyUserControl>()) uc.MainAppClosing();`